# US English vs UK English

Tags: language-evolution, transatlantic-differences, international

Of course, I am not a native English speaker nor a good one (or at least not as good as I would like to be). I know there are some differences between UK and US English, but, from my perspective, they aren't fundamental differences (I probably mix them, unfortunately).

My question arises from the fact that there is a great effort these days to make websites available in as many languages as possible. As I am a technical person, I know how hard is it to do this. So, is this worth it? Does it matter for a native English speaker whether is it UK or US English?

Comment: Firstly, you must realise that the 'US English / UK English' divide is a very broad-brush analysis. I don't even use the terms as being too misleading for many purposes in linguistics. Secondly, there _are_ differences that could lead to misunderstandings and/or cause offence. _But this has been addressed here before._

Comment: Are you asking if a native American English speaker could understand something written in British English and vice versa? If that's what you're asking, the answer is most likely yes. Speaking as an American, I've read lots of things with British spelling and terminology, and it isn't very different from reading American English. The reader might need to Google some unfamiliar terminology (for example, I didn't know that "chemist" meant "pharmacist" until I Googled it), but it'd be no different than reading any other English text with a few unfamiliar words.

Comment: As a native Brit who has also lived for many years in the US, my sense is that the perceived differences matter more to some British people than to Americans. There are many opinionated Britons who seem to think the language 'belongs' to them, and that speakers of English in other countries should still kowtow to British norms. From a linguist's point of view, this is of course nonsensical. In any case, the two variants are much more similar to each other than they are different. The greatest practical differences I have found are terminological ones in fields like house construction and cars.

Comment: The primary differences between the standard versions are in a handful of vocabulary, some few spelling things, and some rare syntax (gotten vs got, at the hospital vs at hospital) and accent (bath/trap split, r-dropping) (but accent isn't relevant for a website). For a website, I would think only spelling would be noticeably different, but only in roughly one word per 500 words.

Comment: You haven't said what specific subject areas might be covered by this/these website(s). But in principle, my suggestion would be to focus less on such relatively minor issues as *got* vs. *gotten* or *color* vs. *colour,* and more on the adjustments needed that might arise from the existence of such things as different construction techniques and their associated terminology,  different names for similar materials and tools, different technical standards, different bureaucratic institutions, and different bureaucratic procedures, legal frameworks and reporting requirements.

Comment: To take @Erik Kowal's comments one step further, the subject of the website would dictate whether a website should have two versions of English.  I can use most UK or Australian Information Technology web sites without problem, but I know I would be at a loss on one for car parts or clothing for example.  Also, Americans still don't use the metric system so any site with measurements would be confusing unless it was for the American scientific community (which has joined the rest of the world).

Comment: Happened to see this blog post.  See the note near the end about the UK and US sites.  http://www.contentrules.com/blog/fun-or-economical-case-study-on-us-vs-german-website

Answer (score 0):

I think this is an interesting question.  As the comments indicate, the domain of content is quite important.

Color vs. colour is no big deal, but if it there are technical requirements it might be a bit of risk.

> As an opinion-based answer, it would probably be easier to solicit input from UK and US native speakers on a site-by-site basis rather than attempt to account for nuanced language differences in code.

As an example of coding challenges, we all know Google translate just doesn't get it right sometimes ([link to amusing Google translate errors](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/10-google-translate-fails.html))

Answer (score 0):

Localisation is important not just for differences in spelling but also meaning. For example if you said to me (North America):

> ... the hood of the car

I would be confused. I would expect to hear (Commonwealth):

> ... the bonnet of the car

This doesn't just apply to UK/US English but the many other variations.